# Back-Up PS3 Saves?

Tags: ps3

Is there a way to back-up your saved games on the PS3 in case they are overwritten?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To back up the save from a particular game there is an easier way than backing up your entire hard drive. Just use a thumb drive in the USB slot, and go to the "Saved Data Utility (PS3)" item in the PS3 menu (it's above "Trophy Collection"). Then select a save file and press triangle, then select copy. You should see the thumb drive listed as a destination.

Comment: This doesn't work for protected saves. A list of games which used save protection can be found here: http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-General-Discussion/Locked-PS3-Game-Saves-Compilation-List-is-Now-Available/td-p/9269692

Comment: Protected games should be storable on the PSN+ [cloud storage](http://blog.eu.playstation.com/2011/03/09/online-storage-available-to-playstation-plus-members-from-tomorrow/) service - of course, as the PSN is down at the moment, this is probably a moot point :)

Comment: Is there anyway to backup up all saves (besides the full system backup) or do you have to select each file and save it?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon: as far as I can tell, you have to do it one at a time, or do a full system backup

Answer (score 9):

Also, saved game backup is one of the features included w/ subscribing to [PlayStation Plus](http://us.playstation.com/psn/playstation-plus/)

Comment: +1. This is the only way to backup protected saves.

Comment: I didn't know this, I might have to reconsider not getting Playstation Plus, do you know if they are restorable on a different PS3?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can back up your PS3 data to an external hard drive.  Watch the following [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04eSR6ZeC3Q) to show you how to do it from the system menu.

Comment: This also does not work for protected saves (or other protected content, for that matter). See the link I posted to Kip's answer.

Comment: To be clear, this *does* backup protected saves, but they may only be restored on the same PS3.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that backing up saved games to a USB thumb drive, and potentially to an external hard drive, doesn't always guarantee saving all of the associated data-- games with online components, like Rock Band, can restrict the ability of a user to backup the data associated with the saved content. I found out about Rock Band's issue the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the full PS3 backup it appears to back up protected game's saves also as I have Dragon Age Origins and after upgrading my PS3 hard drive this weekend I still have the game data. It's possible that having the Dragon Age Complete collection that was released is unprotected making my anecdotal evidence invalid.

Comment: The Backup Utility does backup protected save games, but you can only restore them to the same PS3.