# How can I save a game to a USB stick on Playstation 3

Tags: ps3

I want to save a game to a USB stick on Playstation 3.
When I hit triangle on save data it only offers me online storage. How do I enable USB storage?

Comment: Did you [format](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PS3-Support/Formatting-a-USB-Storage-Device-For-Use-With-The-PS3-A-Guide/td-p/4641934) it correctly?

Comment: See answers, and my comments, here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/back-up-ps3-saves

Answer (score 2):

Copy to USB should be available on the Triangle menu (you're at the system menu, not the in-game save menu, right?). Make sure the USB stick is inserted first and recognized by the PS3 (it should show up at the top of the saves menu). Your USB stick will need to be FAT32 format to work with PS3, most small USB sticks already are, some larger ones may need to be converted.

Comment: Do you also need a folder with the name "PS3"?

Comment: @Reafexus PS3 should make the folder on it's own when you try to copy IIRC